# logging module adds leading spaces in console output

Tags: python, logging

EDIT The blank spaces were added by an obscure statement in the code, somewhere deep in a sub-function. Once this was removed, the logging output is nice... Therefore I close the subject.

The redirection of console logging to `stderr`permitted to highlight this easily, so thanks to commenters!

---

I'm using Python `logging` module to handle logging from my project, both to log file and standard output. This works quite nice, based on a config file, with different logging levels.

Problem: to standard output, lines are starting with blank spaces. This seems to be linked to the time elapsed between two writings (something like one space per second).

For sure, I made an error in logging config file, as I'm really not at ease with it, but I cannot identify where. Changing logging level for all to be set at the same will not change anything. Could someone bring some help?

---

Report file content:

```
2011-10-11 17:25:43,911 : INFO : P-Tool : P-Tool launched from command-line
2011-10-11 17:25:43,927 : INFO : P-Tool : Starting instantiation of tools
2011-10-11 17:25:43,959 : INFO : P-Tool : Initialization completed
2011-10-11 17:25:43,959 : INFO : P-Tool : Execution started
2011-10-11 17:25:44,973 : WARNING : P-Tool : Process Project File CRC check FAILED, [...]
2011-10-11 17:25:44,973 : INFO : P-Tool : XSD version check passed: Process [...]
2011-10-11 17:25:44,973 : ERROR : P-Tool : XSD validation FAILED for Process[...]
2011-10-11 17:25:44,973 : INFO : P-Tool : Process Call found, ID: 1, short name: [...]
2011-10-11 17:25:44,973 : INFO : lib.tools.I-Tool : importing AC_ICD: [...]
2011-10-11 17:25:52,983 : INFO : lib.tools.I-Tool : importing AC_ICD: [...]
2011-10-11 17:26:00,009 : INFO : lib.tools.V-Tool : verifying project [...]
```

Standard output:

```
INFO : P-Tool : P-Tool launched from command-line
INFO : P-Tool : Starting instantiation of tools
INFO : P-Tool : Initialization completed
INFO : P-Tool : Execution started
 WARNING : P-Tool : Process Project File CRC check FAILED, [...]
INFO : P-Tool : XSD version check passed: Process Project [...]
ERROR : P-Tool : XSD validation FAILED for Process Project [...]
INFO : P-Tool : Process Call found, ID: 1, short [...]
INFO : lib.tools.I-Tool : importing AC_ICD: [...]
  INFO : lib.tools.I-Tool : importing AC_ICD: [...]
  INFO : lib.tools.V-Tool : verifying project [...]
 ERROR : P-Tool : no CRC found in "Project\Rep[...]
INFO : lib.tools.G-Tool : generating binary for [...]
 ERROR : P-Tool : no CRC found in "Project\Reports[...]
INFO : lib.tools.LAF Writer : LAF writing started, [...]
```

(note how the lines are starting with blank space)

Here is how I configure the `logging` module:

```
# in the module p_tool.py
# defining the logging
LOG_CONFIG = 'logging.conf'
logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 
                                       'resources', 
                                       LOG_CONFIG))
logger = logging.getLogger('P-Tool')

[...]
# adding some message
logger.info('message to logger')
```

and the logging configuration file:

```
# logging.conf
[loggers]
keys=root,P-Tool

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,logFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,fileFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,logFileHandler

[logger_P-Tool]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,logFileHandler
qualname=P-Tool
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_logFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('p_tool_log.txt','w')

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no other `print`s hanging around in your program? If it is printing to STDOUT at the same time as the logging module, they will get mixed together.

Comment: Why do you specify the date format for the console formatter, when you don't use it in the format?

Comment: Try changing to `sys.stderr` - do you see any change in the console output? If so, Chriszuma may be right about other stuff in your program writing to sys.stdout

Comment: I agree with Chriszuma. It isn't the logging module -- somewhere, something is outputting a space to stdout, and it's not the logging module.

Comment: @Chriszuma: I made a search, found one `print`, removed it, which removed half of the blank spaces. @Vinay: good idea! By redirecting my console call, I can see blank spaces appearing in standard output, and the error output will contain clean log lines. So, now, I just have to identify what the remaining writer to stdout are...

Comment: @Velociraptors I thought `datefmt` was mandatory, as only the `class` entry is explicitly said as optional (as explained in 15.6.20.2 of Python documentation). I cleaned the config file accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written above, I made two mistakes in my code. Therefore, there's nothing wrong with the `logging` module or the configuration I made of it.

The blank spaces were added by an obscure statement in the code, somewhere deep in a sub-function. Once this was removed, the logging output is nice... Therefore I close the subject.

The redirection of console logging to `stderr` permitted to highlight this easily, so thanks to commenters!